# Calculating the joint density function

Tags: probability-theory, density-function

Consider two random variables $X$ and $Y$. Let $Y=aX$ where $a$ is a constant. What is the joint Probability Density Function(PDF) of $X$ and $Y$?

The joint PDF is given by
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y}P(X\leq x,Y \leq y)
\end{align*}
where 
\begin{align*}
P(X\leq x,Y \leq y) &= P(X\leq x, X\leq y/a) \\
&= 
\begin{cases}
P(X\leq x) & \text{, if } x<y/a\\
P(X\leq y/a) & \text{, if } x>y/a
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
In both cases the partial derivative is zero? Am I missing something, are my calculations wrong or does the PDF not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(X,aX)$ does *not* have a PDF, i.e. a density wrt the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^2$.

This because the set $B=\{(x,ax)\mid x\in\mathbb R\}$ which satisfies $P((X,aX)\in B)=1$ has Lebesgue measure $0$.

If $f$ should function as a PDF then we get the contradiction:$$1=P((X,aX)\in B)=\int_Bf(x,y)dxdy=0$$

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind adding how to show that the Lebesgue measure is $0$?

Comment: The set can be written as a countable union of finite line segments and the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^2$ of any finite line segment is $0$. Observe e.g. that $[0,1]\times\{0\}\subseteq[0,1]\times[0,\epsilon]$ for every $\epsilon>0$ where $\lambda([0,1]\times[0,\epsilon])=\epsilon$. Then $\lambda([0,1]\times\{0\})<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$ and consequently $\lambda([0,1]\times\{0\})=0$.